# Запретить кэширование сайта

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, кэширование

Как можно ввести запрет на кэширование сайта или заставить браузер перезагружать все данные с сервера? Сайт - одностраничник и не имеет большого количества файлов. Проблема заключается в том, что после очередного обновления сайта или дизайна, необходимо очищать кэш, чтобы увидеть все эти обновления.

Answer (score 0):

не надо вводить запрет на кэширование, просто после обновления сайта добавляйте какой нибудь хэш к стилям и скриптам, которые обновили, наподобие `/css/styles.css?id=aB457be464`

Comment: а может есть что то в метатегах на обновление? по идее с таким вопросом должен же каждый разраб сталкиваться. и если бы у меня было таких файлов много, то это скорее не было бы оптимальным решением

Comment: @MickroSkate это и есть оптимальное решение))

Comment: @MickroSkate просто это автоматизировать нужно, а не руками делать